Forward request from mockServer to wiremock in Docker
Just started learning about mocks and I am trying to figure it out.
I have wiremock in Docker and mockServer in Docker.(mock-server.com).
Each has simple test requests. /hello returns the string hello. Individually, everything works.
I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that when I access /hello mockServer, mockServer  redirects (forwards) the request to /hello wiremock so that the response comes back from wiremock.
There is an example in the mockServer documentation how to create a forward request
{
  "httpRequest": {
    "path": "/some/path"
  },
  "httpForward": {
    "host": "mock-server.com",
    "port": 80,
    "scheme": "HTTP"
  }
}

But I don't understand how to apply it.
Both have localhost address like:
http://localhost:3001/hellowiremock
http://localhost:3000/hellomockserver

Tried the example from the documentation - didn't work.
EDIT.
I've been trying to make it work.
I've created network and added 2 containers.
I can ping from one container to another.
But, still, I can't create forward request from mockserver to wiremock.
I have tried several variations of this template. The response ether 404 not found or connection refused.
{
  "httpRequest": {
    "path": "/some/path"
  },
  "httpForward": {
    "host": "mock-server.com",
    "port": 80,
    "scheme": "HTTP"
  }
}

The only one that works is this one, but I don't think it's right.
{
  "httpRequest": {
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/test"
  },
  "httpResponse": {
    "statusCode": 302,
    "headers": {
      "Location": ["http://localhost:3000/hello"]
    }
  }
}


The solution I found is to create docker-compose file, add both images to the same network, run mockserver with proxy commands
version: '3'

services:
  wiremock:
    container_name: wiremock
    image: wiremock/wiremock:3.6.0
    ports:
      - 3000:8080
    networks:
      - testnet
    volumes:
      - ./mappings:/home/wiremock
      - ./extensions:/var/wiremock/extensions

    # --global-response-templating For response template
    command: "--extensions=extensions.ResponseTransformerCustom,extensions.HttpMethodFilter,org.wiremock.RandomExtension, --global-response-templating"

  mockServer:
    container_name: mockserver
    image: mockserver/mockserver:5.14.0
    command: -logLevel DEBUG -serverPort 1080 -proxyRemotePort 8080 -proxyRemoteHost wiremock
    ports:
      - 3001:1080
    networks:
      - testnet
    environment:
      MOCKSERVER_PROPERTY_FILE: /config/mockserver.properties
      MOCKSERVER_INITIALIZATION_JSON_PATH: /config/initializerJson.json
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config

networks:
  testnet:

